# How to get an array across the pages?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm trying to get an array across the pages
page1:

```
session_start();
$input01 = array("img01.png", "img02.png", "img03.png);
$_SESSION['input01']=$input01;
```

page2:

```
session_start();
shuffle($input01);
```

Result: *Warning: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in....*
It seems input01 is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shuffle( $_SESSION['input01'] );
```

you better not have register globals on!

Comment: @ Galen, could you shortly explain the second line, pls

Comment: What do you mean by "you better not have register globals on"?

Answer (score 3):

On page2, you have to pull the value from the `$_SESSION` array.

```
session_start();
$input01 = isset($_SESSION['input01']) ? $_SESSION['input01'] : array();
shuffle($input01);
```